# Need to parse a csv file and it should store in variable

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv

I need to parse a csv file and store the value in a variable. Below is the sample csv file

[image: Sample CSV file]

And below is the ./script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

D="";

P="";

./xyz --project "$P" --displayname "$D"
```

For example if we consider the first line:

When i run the script like

```
./script.sh /home/project.csv
```

it should store the values: `10V nmos and pmos for MA` into `$D` and `10v_nmos_and_pmos_for_ma` into  `$P`.

How can this be done ?

Another scenario is, from the csv file if i call first three projects then it should run in a loop row by row

Comment: [PSA: Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/135943)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This assumes very reliable occurrences of '`,`' and '`.`' characters in your CSV:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cat "$1" | while IFS='' read -r line; do
    D="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ',' -f 1 | tr -d '"')"
    P="$(echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 2)"
    echo 'D: '"$D"
    echo 'P: '"$P"
    ./xyz --project "$P" --displayname "$D"
done
```

Comment: This is not working properly, when i run the script with inputs
nothing is getting saved in $D and $P

i mean i cant see value getting stored the Variable

Comment: You'll need to make sure the path to your '`xyz`' executable is correct ('`./xyz`' obviously assumes it's in the same directory as the code (here) being run, and of course that your '`xyz`' executable is consuming its arguments as expected. You can also substitute `foo.csv` with `"$1"` to utilize it exactly as you mentioned (`./script.sh /home/project.csv`).

Comment: remove the last ./xyz for now

If i run the below i dont see any value stroring to the variable

#!/bin/bash

cat foo.csv | while IFS='' read -r line; do
    D="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ',' -f 1 | tr -d '"')"
    P="$(echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 2)"
 
echo $D
echo $P

Comment: `foo.csv` is of course a placeholder. You can substitute `foo.csv` with `"$1"` to utilize it exactly as you mentioned (`./script.sh /home/project.csv`).

Comment: I am completely new to scripting, i have added the script this way

#!/bin/bash

cat /tmp/home/project.csv | while IFS='' read -r line; do
    D="$(echo "$line" | cut -d ',' -f 1 | tr -d '"')"
    P="$(echo "$line" | cut -d '.' -f 2)"
#    ./xyz --project "$P" --displayname "$D"
done

echo $D
echo $P

Please let me know how to do ??

Comment: Hey @Jankyupeblik 
please advice

Comment: I've updated the script in the answer. If you paste it directly into a file named '`script.sh`' and run `chmod +x script.sh`, it should work as you desire (by running `./script.sh /home/project.csv` [`./` assumes `script.sh` is in the exact directory you're currently at].

Comment: Thanks a lot this do work

But as there are lot of rows, so here comes the second scenario

i need to run /xyz row by row

for example first loop it should take the first row values and complete one cycle once it is success then it should store the second row values in the variable and run the second cycle.

Could you please modify this a bit more, it would be lot helpful

Comment: @SiddharthSahoo It will already do that.

Comment: A few bad practices here could justify a downvote: UUOC, use of echo for arbitrary data. But also running 9 commands, 4 of which not builtin and 5 pipes for each line of the file, while `read` can do the cutting itself, and `bash` expansions can remove the quotes by themselves. At least, you've quoted your variables. kudos for that.

Comment: See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

Comment: The only thing more amusing than the unjustified downvotes is the censoring of my comments. :p @Wildcard No, what's bad practice is learning an entire language when you already have a set of tools that does the job.

Comment: @JanKyuPeblik, you mean a pencil and paper?  Yeah, why are you using this computing device you're reading on, anyway?  You already have a set of tools that does the job.  I'll look forward to your stamped letter continuing this conversation.

Comment: I agree with you there, even if it's an idiotic thing for you to say because of the very point you're trying to make. :)

Answer (score 1):

`bash` has no built-in support for parsing CSVs. You could use `ksh93` instead which supports parsing CSV (at least some form of CSV, the one where a literal `"` is entered as `""` within double quotes) with `read -S`:

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
while IFS=, read -rSu3 P D ignore; do
  ./xyz --project "$P" --displayname "${D#*.}"
done 3< file.csv
```

Or use `perl`/`python` with a proper CSV parsing library that you could tune for the exact format of your csv. Example with `perl`:

```
perl -C -MText::CSV -e '
  $c = Text::CSV->new;
  while (($p, $d) = @{$c->getline(STDIN)}) {
    $d =~ s/.*?\.//;
    system "./xyz", "--project", $p, "--displayname", $d;
  }' < file.csv
```

If you can guarantee that the content of the CSV fields won't contain double-quote, comas or newline characters, with POSIX shells like `bash`, you could do:

```
tr -d \" < file.csv | while IFS=, read -r p d ignore; do
  ./xyz --project "$p" --displayname "${d#*.}"
done
```

Comment: I am completly new to scripting, i did something like this

#!/bin/bash

export IFS=","
cat /tmp/test/test_parse/parse.csv | while read a b;
#do echo "$a:$b:$c:$d";
do
echo $a
echo $b
done

But in $a = it saves with 10V nmos and pmos for MA" but i need only the 10V nmos and pmos for MA
in $b = it gives with projects.10v_nmos_and_pmos_for_ma which is correct but i need only 10v_nmos_and_pmos_for_ma

please guide